# Javascript UWP app - maximize app window at launch

Tags: javascript, uwp

I am tring to make a UWP app using JS, but I want the program to be maximized when launched.
Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you to set the full screen status:

```js
var view = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView();
if (!view.isFullScreenMode) {
    view.tryEnterFullScreenMode();
}
```

If you want the application to be maximized automatically when it loads, you can put the above code in the `app.onactivated` function in `main.js`

Thanks.